# Error while trying to generate key on smart card

Tags: c#, windows, smartcard

I'm having an issue while trying to generate a key on my smart card after installing the Minidriver.

Basically I'm using NCryptCreatePersistedKey to create the key and then I use NCryptFinalizeKey to finish the process.

The issue is that when I call NCryptFinalizeKey, I get presented with all the connected readers and need to choose the one I want to use. But when I choose my reader that contains the card I get the following error message: "The card is not fully personalized for use".

Does anyone know what the issue is and how can it be fixed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: See : https://superuser.com/questions/1167625/what-does-the-error-message-the-smart-card-is-not-fully-personalized-for-use-m

Comment: I already saw this question and answer but im not using tpm or virtual smart card, i have a physical smart card and I'm trying to generate key with c# code (using the functions i mentioned above).

Comment: An RSA certificate that contains a key is the same whether you are using it for a virtual card or a smart card.  And is the same if you are verifying or generating.  Did you read the Tech Note link at the link above?

Comment: I managed to solve that issue, some files were missing and i fixed that. The problem now is that it says "The smart card cannot perform the requested operation or the requested operation requires a different smart card". Any idea what could solve that?

Comment: There are different versions of smart cards.  So old versions may not work with some options.  Also Encryption modes have changed so older card will not work with new encryption algorithms.  Then Cards are 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit.  So old card will not work with 32 bit mode.